# How can we sort records by specific value of a filed in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

We want to sort the records by specific value of a filed, for example :-
We have data with country code, name & other details and we want to show records at the top which have country code 'US', after us we want to show the results of country code 'AR'.
so if we are searching for obama, then all obama from US will come first and after that obama from AR will be available in results and we have also want to sort us records base on some rating score.

I am trying filter query with boost but not getting expected data because with filter we are getting only filtered records but we want sort the records basis on boost of specific value of country filed

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                                    "name": {
                                        "query": "obama"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "boost": 2.0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "countryCode": {
                                    "value": "US",
                                    "boost": 4
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "countryCode": {
                                    "value": "AR",
                                    "boost": 3
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "countryCode": {
                                    "value": "ES",
                                    "boost": 2
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 50,
    "sort": [
        {
            "rating": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "_score": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

> Expectation :
>
> All records which belongs with country US should be available on top base on sorting by rating
> All records which belongs with country AR should be available after US's records with respective   rating order
> All records which belongs with country ES should be available after Ar's records with respective   rating order

> Expected example:

```
[
{name:"obama a", countryCode:us, rating:5}
{name:"obama b", countryCode:us, rating:4}
{name:"obama ac", countryCode:ar, rating:3}
{name:"obama ess", countryCode:es, rating:3.5}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tune the score but not drop the document you can use `should`.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

> **must**
>
> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents and will
> contribute to the score.
>
> **filter**
>
> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However unlike
> must the score of the query will be ignored. Filter clauses are
> executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and
> clauses are considered for caching.
>
> **should**
>
> The clause (query) should appear in the matching document.
>
> **must_not**
>
> The clause (query) must not appear in the matching documents. Clauses
> are executed in filter context meaning that scoring is ignored and
> clauses are considered for caching. Because scoring is ignored, a
> score of 0 for all documents is returned.

Here is an example:

```
POST test_stackoverflow_us/_bulk?refresh=true&pretty
{ "index": {}}
{"name":"obama a", "countryCode":"us", "rating":5}
{ "index": {}}
{"name":"obama b", "countryCode":"us", "rating":4}
{ "index": {}}
{"name":"obama ac", "countryCode":"ar", "rating":3}
{ "index": {}}
{"name":"obama ess", "countryCode":"es", "rating":3.5}

GET test_stackoverflow_us/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "name": {
                    "query": "obama"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "boost": 2
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "countryCode": {
              "value": "US",
              "boost": 4
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "countryCode": {
              "value": "AR",
              "boost": 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "countryCode": {
              "value": "ES",
              "boost": 2
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [
    {
      "rating": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```